# Check checkboxes on condition with jQuery and Struts2

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, struts2, jquery-selectors

I have the following code in my JSP:

```
<div class="fieldset_medium_right">
    <div class="checkSoc">
        <s:checkbox name="soc" cssClass="delete"  />            
    </div>
    <div class="checkEnt">
        <s:checkbox name="ent" cssClass="delete"  />            
    </div>
    <div class="CheckUnit">
        <s:checkbox name="ua" cssClass="delete" />          
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I would like that when I check "soc", then "ent" and "ua" become checked too, and inactive.
Also when I uncheck "soc", then "ent" and "ua" become unchecked too, and active.

Here is my code:

```
$("#soc").on('change', function() {
    var ent =   $('input[name=ent]');
    var ua = $('input[name=ua]');

    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
        ent.attr('checked',true);
        ent.attr('disabled', true);
        ua.attr('checked',true);
        ua.attr('disabled', true);
      } else {
          ent.attr('disabled',false);
          ent.attr('checked',false); 
          ua.attr('disabled',false);
          ua.attr('checked',false); 
      }
});
```

which doesnt work but I cant figure out how to make it be fine (beginner in Jquery here).

I tried to inspire from a code that I adapted and made work that is:

Edit: the following code works fine, it does what I want. However I dont know how to adapt it for my own case (ie the code which is above) because I dont have a class attribute, so I would like to use the id and also have some variables to make it look better. Hope this makes it clearer.

```
<div class="elements">
 <div class="class3">
 <input class="class1" type="checkbox" value="1" name="first" id="first" />
 </div>
 <div class="class3">
 <input class="class2" type="checkbox" value="1" name="second" id="second" />
 </div>
  <div class="class3">
 <input class="class4" type="checkbox" value="1" name="third" id="third" />
 </div>
 </div>
```

```
$('input:checkbox.class1').live('change', function () {

  //if the 2nd checkbox is always class2:
  var two = $(this).parents('.elements').first().find('input:checkbox.class2');

  var three = $(this).parents('.elements').first().find('input:checkbox.class4');

  if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
    two.attr('checked',true);
      two.attr('disabled', true);
     three.attr('checked',true);
    three.attr('disabled', true);
  } else {
      two.attr('disabled',false);
     two.attr('checked',false); 
    three.attr('disabled',false);
     three.attr('checked',false); 
  }


});
```

However with Struts it seems that there are no attributes class for the `<s:checkbox>` ,  so I dont know how to proceed. Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: Struts is a server-side framework. The JSP tags are processed to generate HTML, so you want to look at the actual HTML that's generated, then write your jQuery code accordingly. At least until you know how one is transformed into the other.

Comment: @Dave Newton I edited my question to make it clearer, I hope it is now :)

Comment: @Anthony Grist Ok this makes sense, I understand what you mean. I'll have a look at the generated html. But will the html code always be the same? I mean maybe Struts will generate a checkbox with id=ua_01 the first time, then the second time it would be id=ua_03? Or can I be sure it will always be the same ?

Comment: Why not to provide ids for the elements you want to use with selector?

Comment: Ok, so there are no class attribute in the generated html for the checkbox, so I'll still have to use another way to access my checkbox.

Comment: @EColi *Give* it a class and/or ID.

Comment: @EColi Classes are provides with `cssClass` attribute, you can also play with different themes that will change the output generated by templates.

Comment: @EColi As far as I know, Struts 2 doesn't generate any ID unless you tell it to (by specifying a value for n attribute that maps to the HTML `id` attribute on your Struts 2 tag in your JSP). I'm only familiar with Struts 1 though so I can't say that with 100% certainty.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Updated tags.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: S2 generates id-s for form/input tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are using an `#id` selector but the element has no id;
2. you are missing the double quotes, it is `'selector[name="objName"]'`;
3. `attr('checked')` doesn't work, as you can see in [jQuery demo](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#example-0); use `prop('checked')` or `is('checked')`

And all your stuff can be shortened with

```
$('input[name="soc"]').on('change', function () {
    $('input[name="ent"],input[name="ua"]')
        .prop('disabled',this.checked)
        .prop('checked' ,this.checked);
});
```

<kbd>[Running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5a39v/)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, yes I have tried and it simplifies my code. Thank you for your help.